# Repeatable not found when using Spring 4 PropertySource

Tags: java, spring

we are using Spring 4.0.1.RELEASE in combination with jdk6 (this is fixed).
Of course we have done the config in Java with usage of the `@PropertySource` annotation. This leads to an annoying warning message(s) when we compile the project with gradle:

> org\springframework\context\annotation\PropertySource.class(org\springframework\context\annotation:PropertySource.class):
>   warning: Cannot find annotat ion method 'value()' in type
>   'java.lang.annotation.Repeatable': class file for
>   java.lang.annotation.Repeatable not found

This is caused by the usage of not (in jdk6) existing Repeatable class and I am glad that it's just a warning.
I love the clean output of gradle and this is just annoying because it may obfuscate other "real" warnings (like checkstyle...).

Maybe anyone faced the same problem and got a (not so much hack) solution for this situation. I just want to see a clean output again.

Comment: the same trouble with Maven and JDK 1.7.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think that the problem is that in ***Spring 4***, they use [`@Repeatable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Repeatable.html) annotation, which has only been introduced in ***Java 8***.

Therefore, if you're not using Java 8 you'll continue to see this problem, at least until this issue will be fixed.

<del>**BTW**, this is also preventing the usage of `@Scheduled` annotation in older JDKs than Java 8. I hope it will be fixed soon.</del>

Comment: Yes, this is the reason. Our goal was to get a clean output after all. It's just annoying to get this warnings. I am looking for something like a filter for gradle outputs or similar approach.

Comment: See the link below, it might be helpful. 
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/how-to-using-propertysource-annotation-in-spring-4-with-java-7.html
BTW, you may mark the question as 'answered' if you've got your answer :)

Comment: still not fixed in 4.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: @AlonL This does not prevent the use of `@Scheduled` on older JDKs. It just gives the annoying warning mentioned in the question.
I use spring's (version 4.1.1) `@Scheduled` annotation in my Java 7 project and it works fine.

Comment: Still same in 4.1.6.RELEASE

Comment: same for Spring 4.2.1.

Comment: same for Spring 4.2.2.

Answer (score 9):

Just for the records: Use

```
@PropertySources(@PropertySource("classpath:path/to/config"))
```

to get rid of the exception.

Credits goes to: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/how-to-using-propertysource-annotation-in-spring-4-with-java-7.html

Comment: It's just the warning that bothers me. Since I have to use jdk6 the problem still remains unsolved, but thanks for support.

Comment: Or.. if you're using ant and -Werror...  [javac] error: warnings found and -Werror specified

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you just want to get rid of the warning you might be able to achieve this with a custom logger: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/logging.html

I'd check the current implementation, and wrap it in something that filters out the warning you want to ignore, forwarding everything else unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to get rid of the warning below Java 8 is to use the following approach instead of the @Scheduled annotation:

```
@PostConstruct
public void setupTaskScheduler() throws FileNotFoundException {
    taskScheduler = new ConcurrentTaskScheduler();

    taskScheduler.schedule(new Runnable(...), new CronTrigger("0 0 * * * *"));    
}
```